# Asp.net mvc3 application display project directory content instead of main page in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, configuration

I've copied Asp.Net MVC3 application from another source to my development machine.
Now I want to run application, but when I run application the browser show me project directory content instead of application main page.
I suppose a have some mistakes in IIS configuration, but I don't know what is incorrect.
So, what is wrong?

UPD:I did found that "Use Local IIS Web Server" radiobutton in settings window is checked (instead  default "Use Visual Studio Development Server"). Мay be this option affects?

Comment: did you copy the MVC binaries to the server?

Comment: I try to run application on my development machine with installed VS 2010 and MVC 3 from visual studio (open project in VS and press F5). Another MVC 3 apps works fine, but this project not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure the folder in IIS as an Application?  Sounds to me that you've just cloned a folder and expect it to 'just work'.

Right-click on the folder in IIS and select 'Convert to Application'.  On the dialog that appears you will need to change the app pool to 'ASP .Net v4'.

Once you've done that it should work.

Comment: I've use IIS 5.1 (OS Win XP) and Applications is not available in this IIS version...  So, I will try to run application on machine with IIS 6 or later... Anyway, thank you for help me)